# Create Json object using flask

Tags: python, json, flask

I am implementing a python API using flask framework, here is my code:

```
    current_months = [this_month_list]
    result = pd.concat(current_months)
    my_array = np.array(result['city'])
    freqs = Counter(my_array)
    return jsonify(freqs)
```

My problem is in creating the JSON object. 
By the above code the JSON is like:

```
{
'Riyadh': 50
'Jeddah': 10
'Los Angeles': 30}
```

However, I want to include a message to the JSON object. 
This is the result that I want to achieve:

```
{
'Message' : "I want to include this message"
'Result' : {
    'Riyadh': 50
    'Jeddah': 10
    'Los Angeles': 30
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just append them to a dictionary:

```
freqs = {
    'Message': 'Some msg',
    'Result': Counter(my_array)
}
return jsonify(freqs)
```

Answer (score 1):

So just wrap your data:

```
data = {
    'Message' : "I want to include this message"
    'Result' : freqs }
return jsonify(data)
```